# Eclipse wont launch after i upgraded java

Tags: java, eclipse

I just decided to try JavaFX and to do it i upgraded Java to Java 11 and set my default jre to jre11. I changed Path variables and now eclipse dont launch, it just throws an error and send me to the log file. The log file says that my Home variable is not defined but when in do "echo %HOME%" it show me the path to my jdk11..
Also scene builder can launch, just eclipse that cannot.. 
`Here is my log file:`
https://pastebin.com/Z7rVkX4r
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must run it using JDK not JRE.

Comment: it's the same with Java 11, they stopped splitting JRE and JDK

Comment: Just do java path to JDK not JRE (ye, JRE is inside JDK)

Comment: that's what i did :/

Comment: it seems you need nightly build

Comment: so i unistall efxclipse and then i update it to nightly build?

Comment: Work ! Thanks @Antoniossss

Comment: A JRE is sufficient to run Eclipse or a JavaFX application. Because in Java 11 JavaFX has been removed, you have to update e(fx)clipse to nightly or use a [Java 8 JRE or JDK to run Eclipse](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM). The JDK/JREs used for coding have to be specified in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_ and must not be the same as the JRE/JDK to run Eclipse.